Simplify $\begin {vmatrix} (x^2-a^2) & x^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ (x-a)^3 & (x-b)^3 & (x-c)^3 \\\ (x+a)^3 & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3 \end{vmatrix}=0$

Given that $a,b,c$ are non-zero real and distinct constants, such that $$\begin {vmatrix} x^2-a^2 & x^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ (x-a)^3 & (x-b)^3 & (x-c)^3 \\\ (x+a)^3  & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3  \end{vmatrix}=0$$
(i) If $a=11, b=12,c=13$ then the given equation has $m$ solution
(ii) If $a=10, b=-12, c=3$, then given equation has $n$ solution
(iii) If $a=60, b=-12, c=15$, then given equation has $p$ solution
Then which of the followings is/are correct?
(a) $2m+3n=9$
(b) $3n+4p=7$
(c) $5m-6p=4$
(d) $3n+4p=4$

My Approach:  I am not getting any Idea how to solve this problem. No row and column operation is helping me to make this easier So I tried to solve using online calculator and found this result $8x^3(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)(-ab-bc-ac+3x^2)$ but when I saw steps I got scared. Is there better apporach to simplify this problem?
Link to calculator https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-algebra/matrix-determinant-calculator/?i=%5B%5Bx%5E2-a%5E2%2Cx%5E2-b%5E2%2Cx%5E2-c%5E2%5D%2C%5B%28x-a%29%5E3%2C%28x-b%29%5E3%2C%28x-c%29%5E3%5D%2C%5B%28x%2Ba%29%5E3%2C%28x%2Bb%29%5E3%2C%28x%2Bc%29%5E3%5D%5D

Please avoid large/tall formulas in titles. They mess up list displays.

If $L_k$ is the $k$-th line, replace $L_2$ with $L_2 + L_3 - 2 x L_1$ and factor  $8 x$ out of the resulting $L_2$. You are left with
$$D = 8 x\begin {vmatrix} x^2-a^2 & x^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\\ (x+a)^3  & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3  \end{vmatrix}$$
Now replace $L_1$ with $L_1 + L_2$ and factor $x^2$ in the resulting $L_1$. It remains
$$D = 8 x^3\begin {vmatrix} 1 & 1 &1 \\\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\\ (x+a)^3  & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3  \end{vmatrix}$$
Now expand the powers in $L_3$ and remove the part that is proportional to lines $L_1$ or $L_2$. You are left with
$$D = 8 x^3\begin {vmatrix} 1 & 1 &1 \\\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\\ 3 a x^2+a^3  & 3 b x^2 + b^3 & 3 c x^2 + c^3  \end{vmatrix}$$
Now replace column $C_2$ by $C_2-C_1$ and similarly $C_3$ by $C_3 - C_1$ and factor $(b-a)$ and $(c-a)$ from these colums. You are left with
$$D = 8 x^3 (b-a)(c-a)\begin {vmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 \\\ a^2 & b+a & c+a \\\ 3 a x^2+a^3  & 3 x^2 + b^2 + a b + a^2 & 3 x^2 + c^2 + a c + a^2  \end{vmatrix}$$
Replace $C_3$ by $C_3 - C_2$ and factor $c-b$ in $C_3$
$$D = 8 x^3 (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin {vmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 \\\ a^2 & b+a & 1 \\\ 3 a x^2+a^3  & 3 x^2 + b^2 + a b + a^2 &  a+b+c  \end{vmatrix}$$
Finally
$$D = 8 x^3 (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)(ab + ac + bc -3 x^2)$$

$$\begin {vmatrix} (x^2-a^2) & x^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ (x-a)^3 & (x-b)^3 & (x-c)^3 \\\ (x+a)^3 & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3 \end{vmatrix}$$
Adding $C_3$ to $C_2$ and applying identity $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$:
$$\begin {vmatrix} (x^2-a^2) & x^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ 2x(x^2+3a^2) & 2x(x^2+3b^2) & 2x(x^2+3c^2) \\\ (x+a)^3 & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3 \end{vmatrix}$$
Take $2x$ common form $C_2$ and then do $C_2\rightarrow C_2-C_1$
$$2x\begin {vmatrix} c^2-a^2 & c^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ 4a^2 & 4b^2 & 4c^2 \\\ (x+a)^3 & (x+b)^3 &(x+c)^3 \end{vmatrix}$$
Take $4$ common and do $R_1\rightarrow R_1-R_3$ and $R_2\rightarrow R_2-R_3$ and apply identity $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$:
$$8x\begin {vmatrix} c^2-a^2 & c^2-b^2 &x^2-c^2 \\\ -(c^2-a^2) & -(c^2-b^2) & c^2 \\\ 3x^2+a^2+c^2+3x(a+c)+ac & 3x^2+b^2+c^2+3x(b+c)+bc & (x+c)^3\end{vmatrix}$$
Take $(a-c)$ and $(b-c)$ common form $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.
Do $C_2\rightarrow C_1+C_2$
$$8x(a-c)(b-c)\begin {vmatrix} -(a+c) & -(b+c) &x^2-c^2 \\\ 0 & 0 & x^2 \\\ 3x^2+a^2+c^2+3x(a+c)+ac & 3x^2+b^2+c^2+3x(b+c)+bc & (x+c)^3\end{vmatrix}$$
Do $R_1\rightarrow R_1-R_2$ and take common $(a-b)$ from $R_1$:
$$8x(a-c)(b-c)\begin {vmatrix} -1 & -(b+c) &x^2-c^2 \\\ 0 & 0 & x^2 \\\ a^2-b^2+3x(a-b)+c(a-b) & 3x^2+b^2+c^2+3x(b+c)+bc & (x+c)^3\end{vmatrix}$$
Now the matrix is pretty much simplified with, just expand it along $C_2$ and you will reach the result.

You're almost there...
With $$8x^3(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)(-ab-bc-ac+3x^2)=0$$ you will have five solutions; however, we discount three solutions because they will not give us the answers we want (i.e. $a=b, b=c, a=c \implies a=b=c$ do not tell us the number of solutions that satisfy the answers). In addition, $8x^3 = 0 \implies x=0$ is one of the solutions, but is similar to another.
The fifth equation will give us the solutions we need to answer the question. Setting $(-ab-bc-ac+3x^2)=0$ and simplifying, we get $$x^2 = \dfrac {1}{3} (ab + bc + ac)$$  Using the conditions above for (i) through (iii), you can then find the number of solutions, and then determine which of the equations (a) through (d) is correct.
Spoilers:

 For (i) we have $$x^2 = \dfrac {1}{3}(132+156+143) = 431$$ which will give us 2 solutions (hence $m=2$).  For (ii) we have $$x^2 = \dfrac {1}{3}(-120-36+30) = -126$$ which yields no solutions (hence $n=0$) For (iii) we have $$x^2 = \dfrac {1}{3}(-720-180+900)=0$$ which gives us one solution (hence $p=1$. This is also the solution to $8x^3 = 0 \implies x = 0.)$


 Substituting $m=2, n=0, p=1$ into (a) through (d), we find that (a) and (b) are not solutions, but (c) and (d) are.


Shouldn't you count $x = 0$ as a solution?

@Dan - you're right...I'll update my solution above.

Factoring the determinant
Straightforward expansion of the determinant gives:
$$(x^2-a^2)((x-b)^3(x+c)^3 - (x+b)^3(x-c)^3) + (x^2-b^2)((x+a)^3(x-c)^3 - (x-a)^3(x+c)^3) + (x^2-c^2)((x-a)^3(x+b)^3 - (x+a)^3(x-b)^3) = 0$$
Note that all of the difference-of-cubes factors have the form:
$$(x + \alpha)^3(x + \beta)^3 - (x - \alpha)^3(x - \beta)^3$$
$$= (x^3 + 3\alpha x^2 + 3\alpha^2x + \alpha^3)(x^3 + 3\beta x^2 + 3\beta^2 x + \beta^3) - (x^3 - 3\alpha x^2 + 3\alpha^2x - \alpha^3)(x^3 - 3\beta x^2 + 3\beta^2 x - \beta^3)$$
$$= x^6 + 3\beta x^5 + 3\beta^2 x^4 + \beta^3 x^3 +  3\alpha x^5 + 9\alpha\beta x^4 + 9\alpha\beta^2 x^3 + 3\alpha\beta^3 x^2 + 3\alpha^2 x^4 + 9\alpha^2\beta x^3 + 9\alpha^2\beta^2 x^2 + 3\alpha^2\beta^3 x + \alpha^3 x^3 + 3\alpha^3\beta x^2 + 3\alpha^3\beta^2 x + \alpha^3\beta^3 - x^6 + 3\beta x^5 - 3\beta^2 x^4 + \beta^3 x^3 + 3\alpha x^5 - 9\alpha\beta x^4 + 9\alpha\beta^2 x^3 - 3\alpha\beta^3 x^2 - 3\alpha^2x^4 + 9\alpha^2\beta x^3 - 9\alpha^2\beta^2 x^2 + 3\alpha^2\beta^3 x + \alpha^3 x^3 - 3\alpha^3\beta x^2 + 3\alpha^3\beta^2 x - \alpha^3\beta^3$$
$$=(6\alpha + 6\beta)x^5 + (18\alpha^2\beta + 18\alpha\beta^2 + 2\alpha^3 + 2\beta^3)x^3 + (6\alpha^3\beta^2 + 6\alpha^2\beta^3)x$$
All of the even powers cancel, leaving an odd polynomial.  Making this substitution in the original equation gives:
$$(x^2-a^2)((-6b + 6c)x^5 + (18b^2c - 18bc^2 - 2b^3 + 2c^3)x^3 + (-6b^3c^2 + 6b^2c^3)x) + (x^2-b^2)((6a - 6c)x^5 + (-18a^2c + 18ac^2 + 2a^3 - 2c^3)x^3 + (6a^3c^2 - 6a^2c^3)x) + (x^2-c^2)((-6a + 6b)x^5 + (18a^2b - 18ab^2 - 2a^3 + 2b^3)x^3 + (-6a^3b^2 + 6a^2b^3)x) = 0$$
Expanding the polynomial and combining like terms gives:
$$24(a^2b + ac^2 + b^2c - ab^2 - a^2c - bc^2) x^5 + 8(a^2b^3 + a^3c^2 + b^2c^3 - a^3b^2 - a^2c^3 - b^3c^2)x^3 = 0$$
$$8x^3 \left( 3(a^2b + ac^2 + b^2c - ab^2 - a^2c - bc^2) x^2 + a^2b^3 + a^3c^2 + b^2c^3 - a^3b^2 - a^2c^3 - b^3c^2 \right) = 0$$
$$8x^3 \left( 3(ab(a - b) + ac(c - a) + bc(b - c)) x^2 + a^2b^2(b - a) + a^2c^2(a - c) + b^2c^2(c - b) \right) = 0$$
But note that if $a=b$, then $ac(c-a)+bc(b-c)=bc(c-b)=0$ and $a^2c^2(c-a)+b^2c^2(b-c)=0$, so the entire LHS would be zero.  So $a-b$ is a factor of the whole expression.
$$8x^3(a-b) \left( 3\left(ab + \frac{ac(c - a) + bc(b - c)}{a-b}\right) x^2 - a^2b^2 + \frac{a^2c^2(a - c) + b^2c^2(c - b)}{a-b} \right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b) \left( 3\left(ab + c\cdot\frac{ac - a^2 + b^2 - bc}{a-b}\right) x^2 - a^2b^2 + c^2\cdot\frac{a^3 - a^2c + b^2c - b^3}{a-b} \right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b) \left( 3\left(ab + c\cdot\frac{c(a - b) + (b^2 - a^2)}{a-b}\right) x^2 - a^2b^2 + c^2\cdot\frac{a^3 - b^3 + c(b^2 - a^2)}{a-b} \right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b) \left( 3\left(ab + c\left(c - (a + b)\right)\right) x^2 - a^2b^2 + c^2\left(a^2 + ab + b^2 - c(a + b))\right) \right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b) \left( 3\left(ab + c^2 - ac - bc\right) x^2 - a^2b^2 + a^2c^2 + abc^2 + b^2c^2 - ac^3 - bc^3\right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b) \left( 3\left(b(a - c) + c(c - a)\right) x^2 + b^2(c^2 - a^2) + ac^2(a - c) + bc^2(a - c)\right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b)(a-c) \left( 3(b - c)x^2 + b^2(-a-c) + ac^2 + bc^2\right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b)(a-c) \left( 3(b - c)x^2 - ab^2 - b^2c + ac^2 + bc^2\right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b)(a-c) \left( 3(b - c)x^2 + a(c^2 - b^2) + bc(c - b)\right) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)(-3x^2 + a(b+c) + bc) = 0$$
$$8x^3(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)(-3x^2 + ab + ac + bc) = 0$$
$$\boxed{8x^3(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(3x^2 - ab - ac - bc) = 0}$$
Matching what you got from the computer algebra system.
Solving for $x$ given $a$, $b$, and $c$.
(i) a = 11, b = 12, c = 13
Just plug in the numbers to get:
$$8x^3(11-12)(11-13)(12-13)(3x^2 - 11 \times 12 - 11 \times 13 - 12 \times 13) = 0$$
$$8x^3(-1)(-2)(-1)(3x^2 - 132 - 143 - 156) = 0$$
$$-16x^3(3x^2 - 431) = 0$$
$$x = 0 \text{ or } x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{431}{3}}$$
This has 3 distinct solutions, so $m = 3$.
(ii) a = 10, b = -12, c = 3
$$8x^3(10-(-12))(10-3)(-12-3)(3x^2 - 10 \times -12 - 10 \times 3 - (-12) \times 3) = 0$$
$$8x^3(22)(7)(-15)(3x^2 + 120 - 30 + 36) = 0$$
$$8x^3(22)(7)(-15)(3x^2 + 120 - 30 + 36) = 0$$
$$x^3(3x^2 + 126) = 0$$
$$x = 0 \text{ or } x = \pm\sqrt{-42}$$
Assuming that non-real solutions are disallowed, there's only one solution: $x = 0$.  So $n = 1$.
(iii) a = 60, b = -12, c = 15
$$8x^3(60-(-12))(60-15)(-12-15)(3x^2 - 60 \times -12 - 60 \times 15 - (-12) \times 15) = 0$$
$$x^3(3x^2 + 720 - 900 - 180) = 0$$
$$x^3(3x^2) = 0$$
$$x = 0$$
So $x = 0$ is the only root.  This time it's a quintuple root instead of just a triple one, but that doesn't matter if you're only considering distinct solutions.
Choosing the answer
OK, so we have $m = 3$, $n = 1$, and $p = 1$, so we just plug them into the answer choices to check which ones are true.

 (a) is true, (b) is true, (c) is false, (d) is false.

